# Is this a valid array (value)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var leaguetable = new Array(); 

leaguetable[0]= #leaguetable; 
leaguetable[1]= #leaguetable1;
leaguetable[2]= #leaguetable2; 
leaguetable[3]= #leaguetable3;
leaguetable[4]= #leaguetable4; 
leaguetable[5]= #leaguetable5; 
leaguetable[6]= #leaguetable6; 
leaguetable[7]= #leaguetable7; 
leaguetable[8]= #leaguetable8;
```

Can you have ID as the array values like I have done? Because this is not working for me at the moment.

Comment: Add these in single quotes as string

Comment: `leaguetable[0]= '#leaguetable';`

Comment: or use 
leaguetable.push('#leaguetable');
leaguetable.push('#leaguetable1');
so on

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your values inside quotes `'#leaguetable1', '#leaguetable2'.....`

However, you can just use a simple `for` loop to achieve it automatically instead of manually adding it:

```
var leaguetable = new Array(); 

leaguetable[0]= '#leaguetable';
for(var i=1; i<=8; i++) {
    leaguetable[i] = '#leaguetable' + i;
}

console.log(leaguetable);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b3w6N/)**

Comment: Thanks, could you explain what the code does though? Thinking bout this part: for(var i=1; i<=8; i++) {
    leaguetable[i] = '#leaguetable' + i;

Comment: @DuploW It's just increase the i from `1` to `8` and append to `#leaguetable` 8 times so `#leaguetable1`, `#leaguetable2`, `#leaguetable3`..... I'd also recommend you to take a basic tutorial about javascript which is available through out the internet by searching on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Bo, `#foo` is not a valid JavaScript expression. You meant `'#foo'` instead.

Also, you can (*should*) use an array literal instead of `new Array`:

```
var leaguetable = [
    '#leaguetable',
    '#leaguetable7',
    ...
    '#leaguetable8'
];
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I just ask, cuz I never understood it.. What does the "foo" represent? Is it just whatever ur using or is it something specific?

Comment: @DuploW It's an arbitrary name or value for a variable in example code. Could literally be anything (as long as it's a valid identifier); I often use `test` when writing throwaway code myself.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Ah, that's what I been thinking, will be able to understand sample codes more easily now lol. Thanks :P

Comment: @ThiefMaster Why is it better to use a literal array? I find my method easier to check when changing things.

Comment: Which change could you imagine where your way would be easier and more readable?